# Why is my Rails function working in SQLite but not in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have this function in one of my Rails models:

```
def delete_unactivated_users    
  expiry_time = Time.zone.now - USER_ACTIVATION_TIME
  User.where("admin == ? and activated == ? and created_at < ?", false, false, expiry_time).destroy_all
end
```

In `development` mode, with SQLite, it works perfectly well. But in `production`, with MySQL, I get this syntax error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 0 and activated == 0 and created_at < '2014-05-20 10:35:55')' at line 1: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (admin == 0 and activated == 0 and created_at < '2014-05-20 10:35:55'))
```

How can my function be fixed so that it works equally well in SQLite and MySQL?

This would be an excerpt of my `schema.rb` file:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  ...
  t.boolean  "admin",                         default: false
  t.boolean  "activated",                     default: false
  ...
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is what you get when you use different databases for development and production. Expect more surprises to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql doesn't use the `==` - it uses `=` to test equality as well as set a value.

Change it to `=` as that is the SQL standard.

Ie

```
  User.where("admin = ? and activated = ? and created_at < ?", false, false, expiry_time).destroy_all
```